# Bootstrap Carousel Goto Slide From External Link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

**The Problem**

I am attempting to trigger a go to slide in a Bootstrap Carousel by using a hash in an external link, but my function does not do anything.

**What I've tried**

My goToSlide function works perfectly from within the page and I can go to each slide with that function. I thought it was due to the carousel not being initialized so I have tried several permutations of jQuery document.ready and jQuery.when to make sure my carousel was already initialized.

I also tried the jQuery.when with the carousel id instead of the class.
I also tried using the older window.onload to make sure the page was loaded.
I have ruled out the "must be an integer" for the carousel index, since I'm detecting the text hash and triggering the function with an integer. The hash detection works if you'll read the "What This Code Does" section.

**My URL**

http://www.website.com/#business

**My Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery.when(jQuery('.carousel').carousel({ interval: false })).done( function() {
        if(window.location.hash) {
              var home_section = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            console.log(home_section);
            if (home_section == "auto") { goToSlide(0); console.log("went to auto"); }
            if (home_section == "home") { goToSlide(1); console.log("went to home"); } 
            if (home_section == "business") { goToSlide(2); console.log("went to business");}
          }
    });
});
function goToSlide(number) {
   jQuery("#carousel-homebanner").carousel(number);
}
```

**What This Code Does**

My hash gets detected because I can see my console.log outputting the text above, but in the same code block that goToSlide function should fire. I don't get any errors, so I'm assuming it fires.

**The Question**

How do I make the external link with the hash make my carousel slide to the correct slide?

**EDIT My Other Code which also does not work**

```
window.onload = function () { 
jQuery.when(jQuery('#carousel-homebanner').carousel({ interval: false })).done( function() {
        if(window.location.hash) {
              var home_section = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            console.log(home_section);
            if (home_section == "auto") { goToSlide(0); console.log("went to auto"); }
            if (home_section == "home") { goToSlide(1); console.log("went to home"); } 
            if (home_section == "business") { goToSlide(2); console.log("went to business");}
          }
    });

}
```

Comment: I see you have to selector for your carousel (.carousel and #carousel-homebanner) is that because you have 2 slider (in that case you would fire carousel2 when carousel1 is init) or is it just a mistake inherit from a copy-past?

Comment: In this case, there are 2 carousels on the page. I was initiating them by class .carousel and I have also tried initiating them separately with their respective ids. My goal is to detect the carousel init and then check for the hash and run the goto slide function. I only want to trigger 1 of the carousels with the hash link and not the other.

Comment: I just edited the question with my other code.

Comment: If you put a console.log in your function goToSlide() do you have an output?

Comment: Just tested it and it outputs successfully. If you want to see the actual page I can connect with you outside of SO and give you the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84210/discussion-between-rick-scolaro-and-dfayet).

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was that my code examples were, in fact, working. I was basing my failed result on the state of the navigation links, which were not being highlighted.

The trigger was actually happening and there was no error, so each of the examples are fully functioning.

Thanks to [Dfayet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4933917/dfayet) for a second pair of eyes.